# OpenStack Notification Service: Marconi

Tags: openstack

I have ever implemented the Notification service based on RabbitMQ before.

And recently, I am interesting in the OpenStack Notification Service, Marconi.

But I am not sure that how can a client listen to a queue.

I mean a client would be notified if there is a message being pushed into the queue.

Is there any example or tutorial go through the Publisher/Subscriber pattern?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Marconi project (API v1) does not currently support [Push technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology), including long-polling. Depending on how your subscriber processes messages that appear in the queue, you will need to poll the service at an appropriate interval using either the [List Messages](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Marconi/specs/api/v1#List_Messages) or [Claim Messages](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Marconi/specs/api/v1#Claim_Messages) requests.

Keep in mind that polling requests may count towards the rate limits for the service, even when no messages are in the queue. Rate limits are provider-specific.